# elasticsearch rss river not storing content field

Tags: rss, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using the RSS river plugin for elasticsearch to index an RSS feed and it is working great with one exception, it does not store / index the "content" field produced by wordpress. From the source it doesn't look like there is a way to do this but I might be missing something.

Are there any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Or plans to add this to the plugin in the future?

This is the feed I am using: https://blog.mariadb.org/feed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you create an issue in https://github.com/dadoonet/rssriver and I will look at it?
If you could also add some sample documents that would be awesome.

Thanks